# How to show revmob ads in my air for android app

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe, revmob

I'm making an android app with flash cs6, and I want to put some ads in it. I've found that revmob comes with the most specific guide I could find. http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/air.html#download

In the android bit it says: 'Add the required permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file by putting the following code inside the tag.'

Where do I find the AndroidManifest.xml?

I'm going to sound very nooby now, but am I supposed to open my adobe air app inside eclipse in some way, or is my app ready to be uploaded to google play, when I publish it from flash?

Do I need to have uploaded my app on google play before I can start testing ads in my app?

Do I need to upgrade air 3.2?

Any other specific and basic guideline on how to get ads in my app is very welcome.

I think it's very hard to find the clear guidance I need. Thanks in advance.

I have never worked with the xml file before, so I have no idea where to insert the text from revMob.
Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.2">
<id>GalaxyChallenge</id>
<versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
<versionLabel/>
<filename>Galaxy Challenge3</filename>
<description/>
<!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text></description>-->
<name>Galaxy Challenge3</name>
<!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.<name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>-->
<copyright/>
<initialWindow>
<content>Galaxy%20Challenge.swf</content>
<systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
<transparent>false</transparent>
<visible>true</visible>
<fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
<renderMode>gpu</renderMode>
<autoOrients>false</autoOrients></initialWindow>
<icon>
<image36x36>ICONS/NEW%20NEW%20IC/Icon_bigbig/sizes/Icon_bigbig-36.png</image36x36>
<image48x48>ICONS/NEW%20NEW%20IC/Icon_bigbig/sizes/Icon_bigbig- 48.png</image48x48>
<image72x72>ICONS/NEW%20NEW%20IC/Icon_bigbig/sizes/Icon_bigbig-72.png</image72x72>
</icon>
<customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
<allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
<extensions>
<extensionID>com.revmob.airextension</extensionID>
</extensions>
<supportedLanguages>en</supportedLanguages>
</application>
```

And here is the code that is to be added

```
<!-- Required -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

And

```
<application>
<activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first publish your app you should get an xml file created named YourAppName-app.xml. This is the AndroidManifest.xml

You can test ads without uploading to Google Play.

You ideal need to be using the latest AIR SDK from labs.adobe.com which is now 17.0.0.123

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to test this when I get home

Comment: I have added some xml code, do you know where in the xml it should be inserted?